# Devexpress grid with 3 grids

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I recently made some research and couldn't find any solution for my problem.
I have to make win form, and there is one problem.
Bottom part of form contains 3 identical grids (datasource is split on 3 parts for each grid). for example if datasource contains 99 elements, 33 elements will be in each grid.
Problem is that i don't think it is professional to use 3 grids and place them on the bottom of the form. Also, it does not look nice.
I tried to use grid with 3 views but couldn't find solution for that. Found some multiview solutions, but mostly examples for master-detail.

Is there any way i could make 3 views in one grid, with same columns, placed horizontally? Or if there is some control other than GridControl that can provide this?

Comment: You definitely need 3 GridControls

Comment: SO, there is no way of making 3 views in one grid? MultyView is refered to mater-detail?

Comment: AFAIK there is a `GridControl.MainView` property which says the current view in use, based on this, what you ask is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way i could make 3 views in one grid, with same columns,
>   placed horizontally? Or if there is some control other than
>   GridControl that can provide this?

**Short Answer: No**

There is no control in DevExpress controls library which let you display data in views independent of each other.

There are only two possible way to work with multiple vies in the grid control:

- [Master Detail View](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument783)
- [Split Presentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10873).

These are correctly described in Dmitry's answer and go through the documentation too.

You can implement this with GridControl by creating Master Detail View with [Detail Tabs](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument738). Just create temporary dataset for creating relationship for these 3 views data. Split the records and distribute them in 3 tables for making relationship for managing Master Detail relation. Using this approach these 3 view will be tabbed but not visible every time.

Another way, Display spitted records in 3 detail views or in Grouping so that they will be visible to compare with each other. [Grouping Modes and Custom Grouping](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1967) could be the another alternate if single grid control is preferred.

If all of these word around does not suit to your requirement then you must bound to use manually synchronized grids with custom data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can display multiple Views within single Grid when talking about the [Masted-Detail Data Presentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument783). In this case the Grid's underlying data source contains two or more record-sets linked by relationships (called master-detail relationships).

If you are not talking about the Master-Detail data presentation mode, the only way do display multiple views at once within the single GridControl is a [Split View Presentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10873) mode. This presentation mode allows you to divide the grid horizontally or vertically into two view-regions separated by a splitter. In this case the view-regions present the same data and can be scrolled separately.

If you want to split grid more than once, you should create several grids and synchronize their data sources manually.